# 30 push notifications apps in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8

I had read in an article that windows phone allows 30 push notifications for an device

[link here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402558%28VS.92%29.aspx)

And if we add more than that exception raises **PushNotificationChannelQuotaExceeded** but still if we want to add we need to turn of the push notifications of any one app and install new app.

But how do windows phone know the count of the push notification enabled apps and if we disable push notification for any app do it know to which app we disable the notification?

and how does it know if we disable one notification it as to allow another?

and suppose if our app is 31st one and the user installed it until the user starts our app he does not know that he need to disable another app push notification to enable ours.. is it right? as here we are handling the exception in pushnotificationchannel...

Until the user disables push notifications for another app.. at what stage will the app of ours will be?

can any one please tell me the answers...i searched a lot but could not find answers. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no limit in Windows Phone 8 anymore.

Source: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2012/2-019 5min in there